# How do I add a square (about 80% width and height and colored) inside the page?

Tags: html, css

Question in the title. I tried using padding, width, height, divs, ect and nothing worked. Nothing I searched gave me a good answer. Just for context, I want a square like the link below (don't mind the template, that is the best photo I could find for what I want). Thanks in advance!

[Here is what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWY4w.jpg)

Comment: BTW, I'm kinda new to coding so sorry if this seems like a troll question lol

Comment: edit your post, don't post a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is margin. This is like padding, but outside. If you put this CSS rule in:

```
margin: 10%;
```

I am sure it will work.

Margin is a part of the box model, just like padding, border and content. It is a basic part of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It would be beneficial if you share your code.... btw you can also try using padding of 10% in the parent element .